# Moving Commits To Base of Branch

Tags: git, version-control

So I've managed to screw my repo up pretty badly somewhere along the line, somehow.

Essentially, what I now have is a "Master" branch, which contains all of my old version code and a "master" branch (note the different cases) which contains all of the new reworked code (almost entirely rewritten from scratch). Not to mention a bunch of offshoots of each of these two (not too worried about them).

So essentially, what I would like to do is to move all of the commits in the "Master" branch to the base of what is currently the "master" branch and then create a new branch for everything that is currently on the "master" branch.

To illustrate this, my repo currently looks something like this (X represents the last commit before the rebuild and Y the first commit of the rebuild):

```
Master  master
X        / 
 \      /
  \    /
   \  Y
```

And I'd like it to look more like:

```
     newBranch (that was "master")
    /
   /
  /
 Y
X
|
|
|
master (that was "Master")
```

As that more accurately reflects the reality of things (no idea how this got screwed up.

If this isn't easily achievable I'll just bite the bullet, delete the "master" branch from this repo, leave it as a legacy repo and then add the rework into a new one, but I'd rather not do that.

Is it possible? How might I go about achieving this reshuffle?

Comment: Due to default case-folding on Windows and MacOS file systems—in which a file named "hello.txt" is the *same* file as the file named "Hello.txt"—it's a very bad idea to have two branches whose name differs only in case. Rename one or both of them before you tackle the next part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish what you want you could do a rebase, but since the two branches have the same name, beside case, due to OS specific default case-folding, you probably need to rename one branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch -m some_other_name
```

now you have two scenarios depending on which branch the checkout brought you

If you renamed the Y branch do

```
git rebase master
```

If insted you renamed X, do

```
git checkout master
git rebase some_other_name
```

I would expect lot of conflicts though.

Comment: I'm just getting a message saying "Current branch master is up to date." when I run that. It doesn't appear as though the rebase command is case sensitive.

Comment: seems to be OS specific. anyway can you rename master (does not matter which one) to something and perform the rebase?

Comment: With the renaming this worked, thanks! I'll be more careful in the future

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s possible. You can use below commands to change the commit histories:

```
git rebase --onto Master <commit id for Y>~1 master
git checkout -b newBranch
```

Then your `master` branch will rebase on the top of `Master` branch, and you can create `newBranch` from `master`.

**Note:** `<commit id for Y>~1` is the parent commit for `Y`. You should only find the commit id for `Y` (such as `5d2bf07`), then the command `git rebase --onto Master 5d2bf07~1 master` will rebase the commmits from `Y` to latest commit on `master` branch on the top of `Master` branch.